# Get a list of all installed applications in Django and their attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django website, I'm creating a class that interact dynamically with other applications installed in the website. I have to do a manipulation on each field of each application.

So I want to save the name of all installed applications in a list and get the attributes of each one. There is a way to do that using an iterator or something else ?

Comment: From `manage.py` CLI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566919/django-listing-installed-apps

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Under Django 1.7 and above (thanks Colin Anderson):

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_models()
```

Under Django 1.6 and below.

If you want all models, try:

```
from django.db.models import get_models

for model in get_models():
   # Do something with your model here
   print model.__name__, [x.name for x in model._meta.fields]
```

I believe the older function still works.

Comment: Helped me a lot. +1ed the question as well, even if it was the wrong question for the right answer ;-)

Comment: in django 1.7: from django.apps import apps; apps.get_models()

Comment: @Matthew  How can i use app names and model name in django template to create menu ?

Comment: @AjinkyaBhosale for what purpose? Consider writing a complete question (explaining _exactly_ what it is you are trying to do).

Comment: Didn't the OP asked for list of all installed apps.. Not the list of all models...

Comment: Possibly, but they did say "Perfect!" in response, so I guess not.

Comment: See also the comments to the other answers: they were actually looking for models, it was just not clearly outlined.

Comment: In case anyone *does* come here looking for how to get a list of (names of) installed apps, I did it in Django 1.11 with `apps.app_configs.keys()`. This yields a list of app labels. It does the same thing as @caio's response below, but is a little more direct. `apps.app_configs` yields a dictionary with the app labels as  keys.

Answer (score 42):

[edit]

> Since Django 1.7, accessing `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is discouraged: "[Your code should never access INSTALLED_APPS directly. Use django.apps.apps instead.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#installed-apps)" – johanno

So the blessed way is:

```
from django.apps import apps

for app in apps.get_app_configs():
    print(app.verbose_name, ":")
    for model in app.get_models():
        print("\t", model)
```

Older version of this answer:

All applications are registered in the `settings.py` file.

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
['django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.sites', 
 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin', 'raven.contrib.django']
```

You can import each application and list their attributes:

```
In [3]: from pprint import pprint

In [4]: for app_name in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        module_ = __import__(app_name)
    except ImportError:
        pass
    map(print, ['=' * 80, "MODULE: "+app_name, '-' * 80])
    pprint(module_.__dict__)
```

In order to use the new print function instead of the print statement in older Python you may have to issue a `from __future__ import print_function` (or just change the line containing the `print` call).

Comment: Since at least Django 1.7, accessing settings.INSTALLED_APPS is discouraged: ["Your code should never access INSTALLED_APPS directly. Use django.apps.apps instead."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#installed-apps)

Answer (score 15):

You can retrieve installed apps like that (in interpreter) :

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> [app for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
     if not app.startswith("django.")]
['myapp1', 'myapp2', 'myapp3']
```

Answer (score 9):

The list of installed applications is defined in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`. It contains a tuple of strings, so you can iterate on it to access each application's name.

However, I'm not sure what you mean by each application's *attributes* and *fields*.

Comment: For attributes, If I have for example an application with 2 CharField and 2 TextField, I want to be able to get these fields data when I select it. I want to do that for each application installed so it should be dynamic and not hard coded. Thank you

Comment: Applications don't have `CharField` and `TextField` "attributes". Are you talking about application models or application forms?

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining that well, I'm talking about application models : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-types

Answer (score 4):

To get the actual **apps** themselves (*not just names*), this is what I came up with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.module_loading import import_module
apps = [import_module(appname) for appname in settings.INSTALLED_APPS]
```

Though you may want to do some error handling, or filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Django 1.9:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from django.test import override_settings
from django.apps import apps


class DiscoverRunnerNoMigrations(DiscoverRunner):
    def run_tests(self, *args, **kwargs):
        app_labels = [a.label for a in apps.app_configs.values()]
        migration_modules = dict.fromkeys(app_labels)

        with override_settings(MIGRATION_MODULES=migration_modules):
            return super(DiscoverRunnerNoMigrations, self).run_tests(*args,
                                                                     **kwargs)
```

Update your settings to point to this test runner.

Running this with --keepdb is real fast.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Django 1.11+ (I'm working on Django 2.2)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps

# get complete list of all apps
list_of_apps = [apps.get_app_config(app_name.split('.')[-1]) \
                for app_name in settings.INSTALLED_APPS]
# app_name.split('.')[-1] we need, because some system apps has dots in name
# like 'django.contrib.admin', and app_label is 'admin'

# get list of models for one specific app. For example first app in list_of_apps
models_list = [model for name, model in list_of_apps[0].models.items() \
               if not model._meta.auto_created]
# we outfiltered auto_created models, because they are not in models.py
# and had been created automatically by Django
```