# Get a List of Project Specific Apps in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get a list of all the project-specific apps in a Django project? settings.INSTALLED_APPS will give me a list of all apps I have installed, but that includes things like django.contrib.auth. I just want the apps I have generated using the createapp command.

As a follow up question, is there a way to dynamically get a list of every module in a given app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no flag that keeps track of which apps are generated by `startapp`. However you can separate `INSTALLED_APPS` into two lists:

```
APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # ...
]

MY_APPS = [
    'myapp1',
    # ...
]

INSTALLED_APPS = APPS + MY_APPS
```

You can then use `settings.MY_APPS` as a list of your apps.

Comment: Yeah. This is a smart way to do it.

Comment: As of end 2022, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111244/get-a-list-of-all-installed-applications-in-django-and-their-attributes) gets us the list of apps (`INSTALLED_APPS`) with elan as put forward by @nttaylor. To repeat his solution, it is `apps.app_configs.keys()`.