# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account.apps.AccountConfigdjango'; 'account.apps' is not a package

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
    
    
class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'account'
```

As a whole, I have two files the code above is from `apps.py`, but it does not work.
What and where do I have to import the file `apps.py` to make my code run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the settings.py  you will see a list called INSTALLED_APPS, you pass it there example

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',


'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 ]
```

this taken for users apps.py that look like the following

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'users'
```

Comment: I made it, but what could be another reason if it does not help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share you setings.py and folder structure.

Comment: I got trouble with my PC unexpectedly, so as soon as it will be possible) but in advance, let’s say I am using Atom, how to share my folder structure?

Comment: Settings.py


"""
import os

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: can you send you installed apps

Comment: I have only the apps what I wrote above, or may be I don’t understand something, so could you please explain (like the command) to list all installed apps
I' ve tried this, but it didn't work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566919/how-to-list-all-installed-apps-with-manage-py-in-django

Comment: in your setting.py can you show me your installed apps or can you share the project so I can see it for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot **","** after 'account.apps.AccountConfig'

Your code should be like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'account.apps.AccountConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```